# My microSD mounted read-only

Tags: read-only

I know this question has been asked a lot. I've tried all the solutions, such as formatting, reboot, remount, etc. But my microSD still read-only.

I have partitioned my Micro SD into 2 partitions and 1 of partition I mount it as /data in my android and the last one as SD card.

/data is one of the storage space in android (ex : /system, /data, /cache, /etc)

OS : Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Is your SD card RW enabled when plugged in to PC?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [gparted](http://gparted.org/) `sudo apt-get install gparted`? I had the same problem with my new microsd card. Download gparted and format the microsd card to FAT 32 and then unmount/remount. Ubuntu will recognize the card. WARNING this will erase all contents on the card, however the formatting will solve the unreadable properties.

Comment: I have tried with gparted and with dd, in both cases the drive stays write protected. I even did a full scan and didn't found any issues

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different card reader? I've noticed that, for whatever reason, some of my MicroSD cards insist on going read-only with some USB-SD adapters and not others and which adapter to use depends on which card I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary quick solution:

First check the device name

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And the unmount and remount it (assuming your device is `/dev/sdc1`)

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Micro SD card to full-size SD card adapter?  Some of those adapters have a lock switch on the left side.  I re-inserted a card about 10 times wondering why it was suddenly only mounting read-only before I noticed that switch had slipped slightly out of the unlocked position.

Comment: THIS LITERALLY SAVED MY DAY!